# Applying padding to SwiftUI Picker with menu style is causing multiline text

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-picker

I have a Picker with menu style presenting a label with an icon and text. When applying a padding to any views containing the picker, the picker will behave as though there is not enough space and run to multiple lines even though there is enough space.

Sample Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let options = [
        "Some Long Text"
    ]

    private var selectedOption: Binding<String> =
        .constant("Some Long Text")

        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Text("Some Text")
                Picker("Work Type", selection: selectedOption) {
                    ForEach(self.options, id: \.self) {
                        Label($0, systemImage: "pencil.tip.crop.circle")
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(.menu)
            }
        }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            ContentView()
            ContentView()
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might be a layout bug in SwiftUI. There is clearly enough space to put it all in one line, even with the padding. You may want to file a bug report to Apple.

However, you can easily fix this by applying the `fixedSize()` modifier to your `Picker`:

```
Picker("Work Type", selection: selectedOption) {
    // ...
}
.pickerStyle(.menu)
.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
```

This will make sure that the `Picker` doesn't concern itself with external sizing requirements, ignores the proposed with and just uses renders with its ideal size.

Please note that this might lead to unintended behavior. For example, when the user chooses a bigger font size in accessibility settings, the text in the `Picker` will never break and might be rendered off-screen. So make sure to think through all your use cases.

---

PS: You can also use a `Menu` instead of a `Picker` with `.menu` style. Of course, you won't get the selection behavior for free and have to do it manually, but it doesn't have this layout bug.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround!!! It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like intended behavior to me. Because of the padding applied around the `HStack` (specifically at the horizontal edges) there is not enough space to render the form label on one line. If you were to change the size of the screen (for example using an iPad simulator or using landscape mode) the label would have enough room and be displayed on one line. I tested this code on an iPad simulator and it worked as expected.

If you want to force the label text to be rendered on one line, use `fixedSize(horizontal:vertical:)`. Though this can lead to unexpected behavior.

```
Picker("Work Type", selection: selectedOption) {
    ForEach(self.options, id: \.self) {
        Label($0, systemImage: "pencil.tip.crop.circle")
    }
}
.pickerStyle(.menu)
.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
```

Comment: There *is* enough space. You can replace the "Work Type" string with a "!" and put add a border around the `ContentView` and the padding to make it visible.

Comment: Changing the string to "!" doesn't change anything for me, but I might be looking wrong. As far as I know, the `.menu` picker style adds its own styling which includes additional padding among others. Combined with the manually applied `.padding` means there is not enough space. Again, with a different form factor the label renders on one line without issue.

Comment: There is enough space. This seems to be a SwiftUI bug